# Symfony entity - Oracle default SYSDATE not working

Tags: oracle, symfony, symfony5, sysdate

Symfony 5 + Oracle.

Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="CREATE_DT", type="date", nullable=false, options={"default"="SYSDATE"})
 */
private $createDt = 'SYSDATE';
```

Controller:

```
//save entity object to database (createDt property NOT passed, default must be applied)
$em->persist($obj);
$em->flush();
```

Error:
Could not convert PHP value 'SYSDATE' of type 'string' to type 'date'. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime (500 Internal Server Error)

How can I make Symfony apply default SYSDATE at flush?

Comment: Did you try `$createDt = new \Datetime()` in your constructor?

Comment: It's [not possible](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7711#issuecomment-493094358) to use expressions as `default` values.

Comment: @qdequippe Thanks, this seems to be the way (though I still have to solve some date formatting issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can init your date with default value directly in the constructor.

```
class YourEntity {

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="CREATE_DT", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createDt;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->createDt = new \Datetime();
    }
}
```